# JavaScript: Library for observing an object chain

Tags: javascript, data-binding, qooxdoo

Qooxdoo has this interesting way of doing databinding:

```
this.bind('selection[0].name', textfield, 'value')
```

This will update the text field value with the name of the first selected item, when any of the following happens:

- this.selection is set to a new array.
- this.selection is modified so that the first item changes.
- the name property of the selected item changes.

In other words, it watches changes to both the selection property, to the array itself, and to the item, and doing all the listener-management that entails: If selection[0] changes, it stops observing the previously selected item.

Are there any libraries that do the same thing, possibly based on Object.observe or watch.js?